# HTML Parsing c#

Tags: c#, html, parsing, windows-phone-7, html-agility-pack

I am parsing an HTML file and having a few issues.

I am using the below code:

EDIT********************************

Updated Code now working.

private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);

    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(@"http://www.SourceURL.com"));

}

void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var html = e.Result;

    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

    var list = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").ToList();


    var node = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel")
        .Element("table")
        .Element("tbody")
        .Elements("tr").Aggregate("Flight list\n", (acc, n) => acc + "\n" + n.InnerHtml);
       // .Elements("td")

    this.scrollViewer1.Content = node;




       }

    }
}
```

This is giving me this result.

[image]

All results are now being disaplayed as required.

My Question was : How can I change this code to display all the results under all `<tr>'s`

edit############################ XAML

```
ListBox Margin="6,6,-12,0" Name="listBox1">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="Auto">

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Flight}" Foreground="#FF4BCCF5" FontSize="24" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Origin}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="22" Foreground="#FF969696" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" Foreground="#FF05C16C" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: your elements should be on tr not td. You won't all trs not all tds in the first tr tight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the same methods available on as when using XElement this should do the trick

```
var text = list.Descendants("div")
                 .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel")
                 .Element("table")
                 .Element("tbody")
                 .Descendants("tr").Aggregate("",(acc,n)=>acc+"\n"+n.OuterHtml);

 this.textBlock2.Text = text;
```

Comment: I would think that String.Join would be a much cleaner way than using a Aggregate function.

Comment: @Claus måske, måske ikke. I'd say "it depends" To me the above is clear. The code reads as how you would solve the task. Find me these elements, for each of them concatenate the InnerHtml. With string it reads more like: between each or the strings I'm going to provide insert "\n", the strings can be found like this

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/1190957 , I think that's vastly more clear on the intentions.

Comment: @Claus yes and I simply pointed out that to me it's not. Having an FP background reading a Fold (aggregate) it very descriptive. So again it depends, specifically it depends on who reads the code but also on what's the common way to do things like this in the code bsae in general

Comment: Perhaps, but your way uses string concatenation, which is very very slow. Doing a join/implode with a Fold is generally a bad idea, even in FP, since with immutable objects, you're burning memory/performance, without any reason. Using a fold with a mutable state (such as string.Join in .NET), is much more ideal.

Comment: And of course there's the problem as to having a extra `\n` in your output, that needs to be removed afterwards.

Comment: @Claus we're talking a HTML table here do you seriously believe there's going to be so many trs that the _potential_ overhead is a performance problem? I haven't looked at the implementation of aggregate but it's possible to optimizes that implementation so that above (almost) equals a + b + c + d + c which in turm is as fast as join. I dont' think that to be the case but unless you've actually measured a noticble difference in performance in the specific context of the code, don't use that as an argument. A lot more problems arise from premature optimization than it solves.

Comment: The overhead starts at 100 items. I've got apps that parses data with several hundred elements. It's generally considered *good practice* to use a StringBuilder for such a task. Also, the implementation of Aggerate is irrelevant, when you're not using a mutable state. At least you could used StringBuilder with the Aggerate, but it doesn't change that you're rebuilding functionality that already exists in form of `String.Join`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3122/discussion-between-claus-jorgensen-and-rune-fs)

Comment: @Rune FS Thanks for your help, however I am getting an error when trying to use list.Descendants. Am I missing a Method? `Error 1 The type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Xml.Linq.Extensions.Descendants<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>, System.Xml.Linq.XName)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XContainer'`

Comment: @Rhys Take a look at the edit. I'm shooting a bit blind. I don't have the Agility pack

Comment: @Rune FS I just updated my code. VS wont accept List.Descendants as part of the HAP.

Comment: @Rune FS.. Ahhh. Its working now. I will update my code. I now need to each of the results into ListBox's. Any suggestions there? Or should I post another questions. Thanks a million for all your help. I was having trouble getting my head around it :)

Comment: @Rhys you need the content of each td in a listbox or what?

Comment: @Rune FS Exactly. I  have added some XAML code. I would like to beind the content from each td into a listbox in a data template

Comment: @Rune FS I have created a new question around this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296654/how-to-bind-html-parse-hap-to-listbox-datatemplate

Answer (score 2):

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel")
    .Element("table")
    .Element("tbody")
    .Descendants("tr").ToArray();

this.textBlock2.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, node.Select(tr => tr.InnerHtml));
```

simply you can get all the rows by

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel")
    .Element("table")
    .Element("tbody");

    if (node != null)
    {
       this.textBlock2.Text = node.InnerHtml;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this show a code error on list.Descendants and x.Id, saying `Error 1 The type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Xml.Linq.Extensions.Descendants<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>, System.Xml.Linq.XName)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XContainer'.
`

Comment: Im confused, you just added the code I am already using and there is still the problem with list.descendants as it doesn't seem to be valid for HTML Agility Pack for Windows Phone

Comment: For the second code, value isn't declared. For the first, how would I output the results?

Comment: Just tested.. `Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments ` and `Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'`  I really appreciate you helping me.