# How to Bind HTML Parse (HAP) to ListBox DataTemplate

Tags: c#, html, parsing, windows-phone-7, html-agility-pack

I am currently running the below code to parse an HTML link using HTML Agility Pack for WP7.

EDIT ********************************  Code with suggested changes

void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var html = e.Result;

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);

var list = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").ToList();


var node = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel")
    .Element("table")
    .Element("tbody")
    .Elements("tr").Select(n => new Flight()
    {
        Airline = n.Element("td").Single(j => j.Attribute("class") == "airline").Value,
        FlightType = n.Element("td").Single(j => j.Attribute("class") == "airline").Value,
        Time = n.Element("td").Single(j => j.Attribute("class") == "airline").Value,
    }

    );
```

This outputs the below into a scrollviewer

[image: Output]

There are multiple td's in each line for flight, time, airline etc..  What I would like to do is to bind each td inner text to a listbox dataTemplate.

Here is an example of what I think the XAML would look like

```
<ListBox Margin="6,6,-12,0" Name="listBox1">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="Auto">

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Airline}" Foreground="#FF4BCCF5" FontSize="24" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Flight}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="22" Foreground="#FF969696" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" Foreground="#FF05C16C" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Origin}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

HTML Example:

```
 <tr class="">
 <td class="airline"><img src="/images/airline logos/NZ.gif" title="AIR NEW ZEALAND LIMITED. " alt="AIR NEW ZEALAND LIMITED. " /></td>
 <td class="flight">NZ8</td>
 <td class="codeshare">&nbsp;</td>
 <td class="origin">San Francisco</td>
 <td class="date">01 Sep</td>
 <td class="time">17:15</td>
 <td class="est">18:00</td>
 <td class="status">DEPARTED</td>
 </tr>
```

**So the question is:  How do I bind each td results to its own text block?**

Comment: Can you show a better example of the Html?

Comment: What's on each td? The image you posted is clipped.

Comment: @Derek  I have just updated my code.

Comment: @alfonsa Just updates with HTML section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Flight
{    
    public string Airline { get; set; }
    public string Flight { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }    
}
```

This is your code:

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel")
        .Element("table")
        .Element("tbody")
        .Elements("tr").Aggregate("Flight list\n", (acc, n) => acc + "\n" + n.OuterHtml);
```

After

```
List<Flight> flightList=new List<Flight>();
foreach (HtmlNode tr in node){
    flightList.Add(new Flight(){    
        Airline=tr.Descendants("td")
            .FirstOrDefault(f=>f.Attributes["class"].Value=="airline").InnerHtml,
        Flight=tr.Descendants("td")
            .FirstOrDefault(f=>f.Attributes["class"].Value=="flight").InnerText
// Insert other properties here
    });    
}

listbox1.ItemsSource=flightList;
```

Comment: Thanks but a few issues. `Error 1 Cannot convert type 'char' to 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode'` Also the public string Flight is the same as `Flight=tr.Descendants`. I have corrected the Flight to Flight1 but im not sure about the foreach?

Comment: Correct some simple error yourself. We only say idea or method. Don't do copy paste. Most answer don't checked in compiler

Comment: fair enough. Thanks for your help. Also you website has been great for WordPress stuff.

Comment: the reason I ask is because I dont know and have been strugling with this for days. I was hoping you could explain.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple model object that you bind to your UI:

```
public class Flight
{    
    public string Airline { get; set; }
    public string Flight { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }    
}
```

Then use a Select projection to convert your document into a list of flights:

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "FlightInfo_FlightInfoUpdatePanel")
    .Element("table")
    .Element("tbody")
    .Elements("tr").Aggregate("Flight list\n", (acc, n) => acc + "\n" + n.OuterHtml);

List<Flight> flights = node.Elements("td").Select(i =>
           new Flight()
           {
              Airline = i.Element("td").Single(j => j.Attribute("class") == "airline").Value,
              Flight = i.Element("td").Single(j => j.Attribute("class") == "flight").Value,
              ...
           }
```

Then bind this list of Flight instances to your UI.

I am not familiar with HTML Agility Pack, so I am assuming that its Linq API is similar, or the same as Linq to XML. You might have to tweak the query code above a little bit, but the general approach should be fine.

Comment: I was thinking of a simliar approach, but there is no node.Elements only ElementAt<> or ElementAtOrDefault<>. Also are you missing a closing bracket for .Select(i => ....?

Comment: @Rhys just replace the Aggregate with Select(n=> new Flight...). Part of the reason why I chose the Aggregate in your first question was that I expected you might need to project the results rather than simply print them.

Comment: @Rune FS I have made the requested changes, but HTML Agility pack doesn't have a defination for single. Any more ideas?

Comment: @rhys use an xpath instead "//[@class=airline]" one of the methods for a Node accepts an xpath

Comment: @Rune FS I thought HTML Agility Pack didn't support XPath? I know its a pain, but is there any chance you could provide me with some code so I understand better. Thanks again.